# What do parenthesis mean in regex?

Tags: python, regex, django

I am going through django tutorial from the link below:

```
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial03/
```

Here is a regular expression,

```
r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$'
```

I am not being able to understand what parenthesis actually mean? Can anyone describe me in a single line in lame English? :-)

Comment: From the link you quoted: `Using parentheses around a pattern “captures” the text matched by that pattern and sends it as an argument to the view function`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about being unable to read the __referenced__ manual.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(..)` captures a matched string as a group.

```
>>> import re
>>> matched = re.search(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', '123/')
>>> matched
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000002B3DB70>
```

You can retrieve it later by number (Group numbers are starting from `1`) using [`group` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group). **NOTE** `/` also matched the pattern, but not returned by `group(1)` because it is not captured as group.

```
>>> matched.group(1)
'123'
```

by name (In case you used `(?P<name>...)` - named capturing group):

```
>>> matched.group('poll_id')
'123'
```

There's also group `0` - entired matched string:

```
>>> matched.group(0)
'123/'
>>> matched.group()
'123/'
```

Comment: Rather `(?P<name>regex)` is a named capturing group, as opposed to unnamed capturing group `(regex)`

Comment: @Nabin: `?` is part of the syntax for named capturing group.

Comment: @nhahtdh, Thank you for comment. I add mention about named capturing group according to you.

Comment: @Nabin, According to [Python documentation - `re` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html): This is an extension notation (a '?' following a '(' is not meaningful otherwise). The first character after the '?' determines what the meaning and further syntax of the construct is. Extensions usually do not create a new group; (?P<name>...) is the only exception to this rule. Following are the currently supported extensions.

Comment: so everytime parenthesis is used it should be followed by "?"

Comment: so everytime parenthesis is used it should be followed by "?"

Comment: @Nabin: Not really. `?` is just part of the syntax for named capturing group `(?P<name>regex)`, just like the `P` and `<` and `>`. Only `name` and `regex` can be varied.

Comment: So it means i can change the "<poll_id>" and "\d+" "only???"

Comment: @Nabin, Yes, you can. BTW, if you change `\d+`, it will not match digits  according to the change.

Comment: Last question.. :-) See i have edited the above comment..

Comment: ya i know about \d+ :-) Thank you so much